# Android: playing a lot of short length audio tracks in different activities

Tags: android, audio, android-activity, media-player

I have 10 similar activities and in each i have 2 audio tracks.
I try creating 2 media player each time an activity is created and release it each time I move to another activity but the memory won't actually release and after some time the app crashes.
How can I play a lot of different audio tracks without having the app crashes on me?
here is the code of one of the activities:

```
public class First extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

private static MediaPlayer audio1,audio2;
public static Intent right, left;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.first);
    audio1 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.audio1);
    audio2 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.audio2);
    setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);


    ImageView button1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    ImageView button2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    ImageView left = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.left);
    ImageView right = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.right);
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    button2.setOnClickListener(this);
    left.setOnClickListener(this);
    right.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View item) {
    if(item.getId() == R.id.button2) 
    {
        audio1.start();
    }
    else if(item.getId() == R.id.button1)
    {
        audio2.start();
    }
    else if(item.getId() == R.id.left)
    {
        left = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Tenth.class);
        left.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        startActivity(left);
        finish();
    }
    else if(item.getId() == R.id.right)
    {
        right = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Second.class);
        right.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        startActivity(right);
        finish();
    }       
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    audio1.stop();
    audio2.stop();
    audio1.release();
    audio2.release();
    audio1 = audio2 = null;
    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

Comment: Why is your MediaPlayer declared static then?

Comment: @Mighter , I didn't pay any attention to that, but it seems that is the exact problem. Thank you! Would you like to make it an answer so I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in comment, the problem might be a `static` modifier in member declaration. There's no need to do it and it might lead to memory problems.